# Storing foreign key linked in a separate table? SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I went through Odoo database design and I saw that they stored the relationship between 2 tables in a separate table that doesn't have primary key. How are you able to do this? I want to replicate this kind of behavior in SQL Server. Is it auto-inserted?

Comment: Wihtout the specific details it won't be easy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A table should **always** have a primary key. Look at the thousands of questions on Stackoverflow that ask how to delete one of two identical rows in a database table.

You typically model m-to-n relationships between tables with a separate table that has foreign keys to both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
   person_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   name text,
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE game (
   game_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   name text NOT NULL,
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE likes_to_play (
   person_id bigint REFERENCES person NOT NULL,
   game_id   bigint REFERENCES game   NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (person_id, game_id)
);

CREATE INDEX ON likes_to_play (game_id);
```

The primary key on the table makes sure there are no superfluous double entries and backs one of the foreign keys. The other index is created for the other foreign key.